# Problem Regarding Unknown Ages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If Amanda is $20$ years old. Abby is $1$ year older than Alex. In $8$ years, the sum of Abby's and Alex's ages then will be $75$% the sum of Amanda's and Alex's ages then. Determine Alex's present age.

The stated solution to this problem is $8$ years old. I attempted a few different ways that I thought the problem could be done and kept getting decimal answers, specifically $8.8$

Any confirmations of the $8$ answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: one equation is $\,y+8+x+8 = \frac{3}{4}(20+8+x+8)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether Alex's present age being $8$ works with

- Amanda is $20$
- Abby is $1$ year older than Alex, so is $9$

so in $8$ years times

- Alex will be $16$
- Amanda will be $28$
- Abby will be $17$
- The sum of Abby's and Alex's ages will be $33$
- The sum of Amanda's and Alex's ages will be $44$
- $33$ is $75\%$ of $44$

That seems to work

To do the calculation, suppose Alex's age is $x$.  Then we have $$(x+1+8)+(x+8)= \tfrac34((20+8)+(x+8))$$ i.e. $$2x+17=\tfrac34(36+x)$$ $$8x+68=108+3x$$ $$5x=40$$ $$x=8$$